# Flutter with Getx package - Null check operator used on a null value

Tags: flutter, firebase, flutter-getx

I am building an app to display data of medical providers store in `Firebase realtime database`. I use Getx for state management. I have a listview to display all of the available categories. when I click on the categories I pass a string which is a node in the database. but I keep getting `Null check operator used on a null value` despite making sure that I am passing the correct value.

Here is my MedicalProviderController class

```
  class MedicalProviderController extends GetxController {
      String? medicalProviderType;
    
      late DatabaseReference _medicalProviderRef;
    
      var medProvidersList = <MedicalProvider>[].obs;
    
      var filteredList = <MedicalProvider>[].obs;
    
      var selectedCity = 'city'.obs;
      var selectedSpecialty = 'specialty'.obs;
      var searchQuery = ''.obs;
      var isLoading = false.obs;
    
      MedicalProviderController();
    
      MedicalProviderController.withType({required this.medicalProviderType})
          : super();
    
      @override
      void onInit() {
        super.onInit();
        getProvidersData();
      }
    
      void getProvidersData() {
        isLoading.value = true;
    
        _medicalProviderRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance
            .ref()
            .child('medical_provider')
            .child(medicalProviderType!);
    
        _medicalProviderRef.onValue.listen((event) {
          final providerData = event.snapshot.value as Map<dynamic, dynamic>;
          medProvidersList.clear();
    
          providerData.forEach((key, value) {
            final medProvider = MedicalProvider(
                key: key,
                nameKu: value['nameKu'],
                specialization: value['specialization'],
                phone: value['phone'],
                city: value['city'],
                imageUrl: value['imageUrl'],
                isFeatured: value['isFeatured']);
    
            medProvidersList.add(medProvider);
          });
    
          filteredProviders();
          isLoading.value = false;
        });
      }
    
      void filteredProviders() {
        filteredList.assignAll(medProvidersList);
    
        if (selectedCity.value != 'city') {
          filteredList.removeWhere((element) =>
              element.city.toLowerCase() != selectedCity.value.toLowerCase());
        }
    
        if (searchQuery.value.isNotEmpty) {
          filteredList.removeWhere((element) => !element.nameKu
              .toLowerCase()
              .contains(searchQuery.value.toLowerCase()));
        }
      }
    
      void onSelectedCityChanged(String value) {
        selectedCity.value = value;
        filteredProviders();
      }
    
      void onSearchQueryChanged(String value) {
        searchQuery.value = value;
        filteredProviders();
      }
}
```

and here my screen to display the data

```
class MedProviderScreen extends StatelessWidget {


 final String medProviderType;

  const MedProviderScreen({Key? key, required this.medProviderType})
      : super(key: key);



@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

final medProviderController = Get.put(MedicalProviderController.withType(
    medicalProviderType: medProviderType));

return Scaffold(
  body: SafeArea(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          height: size.height * 0.3,
          color: AppTheme.primaryColor,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        filled: true,
                        fillColor: AppTheme.whiteColor,
                        hintText: 'search'.tr,
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8))),
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      medProviderController.onSearchQueryChanged(value);
                      medProviderController.filteredProviders();
                    }),
                const SizedBox(height: 8),
                citiesDropDownMenu(
                    value: medProviderController.selectedCity.value,
                    onChangeFun: (value) {
                      medProviderController.onSelectedCityChanged(value);
                      medProviderController.filteredProviders();
                    })
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
            child: Obx(() {
              final filteredData = medProviderController.filteredList;
              if (medProviderController.isLoading.value) {
                return const CircularProgressIndicator();
              } else if (filteredData.isEmpty) {
                return const Text('empty');
              } else {
                return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: filteredData.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      final medProvider = filteredData[index];

                      return SizedBox(
                        height: 75,
                        child: ListTile(
                          leading: CircleAvatar(
                            foregroundImage:
                                NetworkImage(medProvider.imageUrl),
                          ),
                          title: Text(medProvider.nameKu),
                          trailing: Text(medProvider.city),
                        ),
                      );
                    });
              }
            }),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

}
}
and here is code of when I click the listview items

```
child: InkWell(
                              splashColor: AppTheme.lightGreen,
                              onTap: () {
                                //  handleCategoriesNavigation(index, context);

                                Navigator.push(
                                    context,
                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) =>
                                             const MedProviderScreen(
                                              medProviderType: 'doctor',
                                            )));
                              },
                            ),
```

I get the error in my home screen and not when I click to navigate to the other screen.
It is worth mentioning that I have created this functionality once before but I had only one constructor in my controller class. this time I have 2 constructors.

**update**
what is causing the problem is controller class is being initialized in the home screen with default constructor that has no String parameter, I don't understand why this is happening even though I have 2 constructors.